How to plot R squared value from pyspark DataFrame?
to recreate the issue
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Window, DataFrame
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
# from recommenders.utils.spark_utils import start_or_get_spark
# from recommenders.evaluation.spark_evaluation import SparkRatingEvaluation
from pyspark.mllib.evaluation import RegressionMetrics, RankingMetrics
import numpy as np
import os

COL_USER = "UserId"
COL_ITEM = "MovieId"
COL_RATING = "Rating"
COL_PREDICTION = "Rating"

HEADER = {
    "col_user": COL_USER,
    "col_item": COL_ITEM,
    "col_rating": COL_RATING,
    "col_prediction": COL_PREDICTION,
}

class SparkRatingEvaluation:
    """Spark Rating Evaluator"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        rating_true,
        rating_pred,
        col_user = COL_USER,
        col_item = COL_ITEM,
        col_rating = COL_RATING,
        col_prediction = COL_PREDICTION,
    ):
        """Initializer.

        This is the Spark version of rating metrics evaluator.
        The methods of this class, calculate rating metrics such as root mean squared error, mean absolute error,
        R squared, and explained variance.

        Args:
            rating_true (pyspark.sql.DataFrame): True labels.
            rating_pred (pyspark.sql.DataFrame): Predicted labels.
            col_user (str): column name for user.
            col_item (str): column name for item.
            col_rating (str): column name for rating.
            col_prediction (str): column name for prediction.
        """
        self.rating_true = rating_true
        self.rating_pred = rating_pred
        self.col_user = col_user
        self.col_item = col_item
        self.col_rating = col_rating
        self.col_prediction = col_prediction

        # Check if inputs are Spark DataFrames.
        if not isinstance(self.rating_true, DataFrame):
            raise TypeError(
                "rating_true should be but is not a Spark DataFrame"
            )  # pragma : No Cover

        if not isinstance(self.rating_pred, DataFrame):
            raise TypeError(
                "rating_pred should be but is not a Spark DataFrame"
            )  # pragma : No Cover

        # Check if columns exist.
        true_columns = self.rating_true.columns
        pred_columns = self.rating_pred.columns

        if rating_true.count() == 0:
            raise ValueError("Empty input dataframe")
        if rating_pred.count() == 0:
            raise ValueError("Empty input dataframe")

        if self.col_user not in true_columns:
            raise ValueError("Schema of rating_true not valid. Missing User Col")
        if self.col_item not in true_columns:
            raise ValueError("Schema of rating_true not valid. Missing Item Col")
        if self.col_rating not in true_columns:
            raise ValueError("Schema of rating_true not valid. Missing Rating Col")

        if self.col_user not in pred_columns:
            raise ValueError(
                "Schema of rating_pred not valid. Missing User Col"
            )  # pragma : No Cover
        if self.col_item not in pred_columns:
            raise ValueError(
                "Schema of rating_pred not valid. Missing Item Col"
            )  # pragma : No Cover
        if self.col_prediction not in pred_columns:
            raise ValueError("Schema of rating_pred not valid. Missing Prediction Col")

        self.rating_true = self.rating_true.select(
            col(self.col_user),
            col(self.col_item),
            col(self.col_rating).cast("double").alias("label"),
        )
        self.rating_pred = self.rating_pred.select(
            col(self.col_user),
            col(self.col_item),
            col(self.col_prediction).cast("double").alias("prediction"),
        )

        self.y_pred_true = (
            self.rating_true.join(
                self.rating_pred, [self.col_user, self.col_item], "inner"
            )
            .drop(self.col_user)
            .drop(self.col_item)
        )

        self.metrics = RegressionMetrics(
            self.y_pred_true.rdd.map(lambda x: (x.prediction, x.label))
        )

    def rmse(self):
        """Calculate Root Mean Squared Error.

        Returns:
            float: Root mean squared error.
        """
        return self.metrics.rootMeanSquaredError

    def mae(self):
        """Calculate Mean Absolute Error.

        Returns:
            float: Mean Absolute Error.
        """
        return self.metrics.meanAbsoluteError

    def rsquared(self):
        """Calculate R squared.

        Returns:
            float: R squared.
        """
        return self.metrics.r2

    def exp_var(self):
        """Calculate explained variance.

        Note:
           Spark MLLib's implementation is buggy (can lead to values > 1), hence we use var().

        Returns:
            float: Explained variance (min=0, max=1).
        """
        var1 = self.y_pred_true.selectExpr("variance(label-prediction)").collect()[0][0]
        var2 = self.y_pred_true.selectExpr("variance(label)").collect()[0][0]

        if var1 is None or var2 is None:
            return -np.inf
        else:
            # numpy divide is more tolerant to var2 being zero
            return 1 - np.divide(var1, var2)

def start_or_get_spark(
    app_name="Sample",
    url="local[*]",
    memory="10g",
    config=None,
    packages=None,
    jars=None,
    repositories=None,
):
    """Start Spark if not started

    Args:
        app_name (str): set name of the application
        url (str): URL for spark master
        memory (str): size of memory for spark driver. This will be ignored if spark.driver.memory is set in config.
        config (dict): dictionary of configuration options
        packages (list): list of packages to install
        jars (list): list of jar files to add
        repositories (list): list of maven repositories

    Returns:
        object: Spark context.
    """

    submit_args = ""
    if packages is not None:
        submit_args = "--packages {} ".format(",".join(packages))
    if jars is not None:
        submit_args += "--jars {} ".format(",".join(jars))
    if repositories is not None:
        submit_args += "--repositories {}".format(",".join(repositories))
    if submit_args:
        os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "{} pyspark-shell".format(submit_args)

    spark_opts = [
        'SparkSession.builder.appName("{}")'.format(app_name),
        'master("{}")'.format(url),
    ]

    if config is not None:
        for key, raw_value in config.items():
            value = (
                '"{}"'.format(raw_value) if isinstance(raw_value, str) else raw_value
            )
            spark_opts.append('config("{key}", {value})'.format(key=key, value=value))

    if config is None or "spark.driver.memory" not in config:
        spark_opts.append('config("spark.driver.memory", "{}")'.format(memory))

    # Set larger stack size
    spark_opts.append('config("spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss4m")')
    spark_opts.append('config("spark.driver.extraJavaOptions", "-Xss4m")')

    spark_opts.append("getOrCreate()")
    return eval(".".join(spark_opts))

I have the actual and the prediction data frames following which then used to calculate the r2 value:
x_true = pd.DataFrame({COL_USER: [1, 2, 3, 4], COL_ITEM: [5, 6, 7, 8], COL_RATING: [9, 10, 11, 12]})
x_pred = pd.DataFrame({COL_USER: [1, 2, 3, 4], COL_ITEM: [5, 6, 7, 8], COL_RATING: [13, 14, 15, 16]})
spark = start_or_get_spark("EvaluationTesting", "local")
X_true = spark.createDataFrame(x_true)
X_pred = spark.createDataFrame(x_pred)
sre = SparkRatingEvaluation(X_true, X_pred, **HEADER)
r2 = sre.rsquared()
print(r2)

plt.annotate("r-squared = {:.3f}".format(r2_score(X_true, x_pred)), (0, 1))
plt.show()

I want to visualize the result in Scatterplot. I have tried annotating but it is not working. It's showing: InvalidParameterError: The 'y_true' parameter of r2_score must be an array-like. Got DataFrame[UserId: bigint, MovieId: bigint, Rating: bigint] instead.

in your code, you passed X_true, x_pred. The first one X_true is a spark dataframe, then x_pred is a pandas dataframe, I think you wanted to use both spark dataframes (the answer will be the same if both are pandas dataframes), then another mistake was to pass the whole dataframes, where it only takes list/array as inputs
selecting just the Rating columns:
X_true_Rating = [row[COL_RATING] for row in X_true.select(COL_RATING).collect()]
X_pred_Rating = [row[COL_RATING] for row in X_pred.select(COL_RATING).collect()]

would have helped if you created the plot first
plt.scatter(X_true_Rating, X_pred_Rating)

Then your annotation was in (0,1), but your x-axis started from 9 and y-axis from 13, so you couldn't see the annotation
plt.annotate("r-squared = {:.3f}".format(r2_score(X_true_Rating, X_pred_Rating)), (min(X_true_Rating), max(X_pred_Rating)))
plt.show()


thank you. This is exactly what I want. I still practice visualizing evaluation metrics. For other metrics such as MAE, RMSE,... can I use the same code as this?

Yes, will work with pandas dataframes as well, plt.scatter(x_true[COL_RATING], x_pred[COL_RATING])
plt.annotate("r-squared = {:.3f}".format(r2_score(x_true[COL_RATING], x_pred[COL_RATING])), (min(x_true[COL_RATING]), max(x_pred[COL_RATING])))

You're welcome ^_^ you can upvote this and then accept it as the answer to close this issue if this answer satisfies the stated problem

based on the request of also adding MAE and RMSE evaluation to the annotation
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score, mean_absolute_error, mean_squared_error
plt.annotate(f"r-squared = {r2_score(X_true_Rating, X_pred_Rating):.3f}\nMAE = {mean_absolute_error(X_true_Rating, X_pred_Rating):.3f}\nRMSE = {mean_squared_error(X_true_Rating, X_pred_Rating, squared=False):.3f}", (min(X_true_Rating), max(X_pred_Rating)))
plt.show()

this is an extension of the previous answer. The previous answer perfectly solved the question so added this as a separate answer

@tran-su this solves the query you had from the comments

I faced a similar problem, for this what you can do is to convert the spark dataframes back to the pandas dataframes and then create a scatter plot for the true ratings vs the predicted ratings and then annotate that with the scatter plot.
To convert :
x_true=X_true.toPandas() #direct function to convert
x_pred=X_pred.toPandas()

To plot:
plt.scatter(x_true[COL_RATING], x_pred[COL_RATING], label='Data Points')
plt.xlabel('True Ratings')
plt.ylabel('Predicted Ratings')
plt.title('True vs Predicted Ratings')

Then plot as you'd like , I'd prefer doing it as follows:
plt.annotate(f"R-squared = {r2:.3f}", xy=(0.05, 0.95), xycoords='axes fraction', fontsize=12,horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='top')


why to convert the spark dataframes back to the pandas dataframes in the first place?

@TowsifAhamedLabib while previously working on a dataset, I found it more convenient to use pandas as it really works well when plotting with matplotlib, however we can also directly plot it using seaborn if we have to continue with spark.

converting to pandas is useless here, what you changed is using x_true[COL_RATING], x_pred[COL_RATING] single columns, where the questioner was passing the whole DataFrame X_true, x_pred ; but this answer doesn't explain anything about what was done wrong in the question, seems like an AI-generated answer

another mistake is in annotating you used the r2 variable where the question used r2_score from sklearn.metrics

thanks for all your support
